# Finding X,Y coordiates on a line with a given length

Tags: geometry, integers

If you have a basic line equations $y = mx + b$ where $m$ is the gradient of the slope. where $b=0$ (where is crosses the $y$ axis) the start of the line is $(0,0)$

What is the most efficient and accurate method of determine the $x$,$y$ coordinate at the end of the line if you know only know the length of the line and the degrees of slope.

Answer (score 0):

You know the angle, so $m = (y/x) = tan(\theta)$

I'm not too sure what you mean by "length of the line", but assuming that you're considering a point on the line, and the "length" is the distance of the point from $O$, we have $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

So you can substitute and have a look. Depending on the angle, discard and retain the $\pm$ signs you'll obtain due to $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the straight line in the slope intercept form is :
$$y=mx+c$$ where the quantity $m$ is the slope of the line and $c$ is that point on the $y$ Axis which the line cuts(y-intercept).
[image]
Now if the line $y=mx+c$ passes through a point say $H(h,k)$ and it has a length $L$ and you need to find the coordinates of the end point $A(a,b)$, we can use trigonometry and the distance formula.

[image]
We know the length $AH=L$, the slope is know to be $$m=\frac{b-k}{a-h}$$
$$L=\sqrt{(a-h)^2+(b-k)^2}$$
[image]
In your particular case, $h=0,k=0$ and the end point $A(a,b)$ can be found as :
$$a=AH \cos \theta = L \cos \theta$$
$$b = AH \sin \theta = L \sin \theta$$
where
$$ \theta = \tan^{-1}(m)$$
Hope this helps ...